# Convert XDocument code to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

Hello guys I'm trying to convert the code below from XDocument to XmlDocument (I need it in XmlDocument) do you have idea about the different methods that need to be changed? I looked for some of them in the XmlDocument and XElement classes but my changes didn't compile.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;  

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Parent", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Child", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Attribute", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            foreach(XElement parent in root.Elements())
            {
                string parentTag = parent.Name.LocalName;

                foreach (XElement child in parent.Elements())
                {
                    string childTag = child.Name.LocalName;

                    foreach (XAttribute attribute in child.Attributes())
                    {
                        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { parentTag, childTag, attribute.Name, (string)attribute });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The libraries are quite different from each other, but it really wouldn't take you long to refactor this code by just seeing what intellisense tells you to do.

Comment: Why do you need to do the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than refactoring your existing code base, why not read the final `XDocument` into a new `XmlDocument`?

```cs
XDocument xDocument = 
    XDocument.Load("file.xml");

...other manipulations...

XmlDocument xmlDocument =
    new XmlDocument();

// Read the XDocument as a simple XML string:
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xDocument.ToString());

// Alternatively, read the XDocument with an XmlReader:
xmlDocument.Load(xDocument.CreateReader());
```